# How to style a charfield which has choices in it django or which widget to use?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Okay so what I really want to do is to style a charfield which has choices from my forms.py modelform class.

My models.py has this code it it...

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
cat_choices = (
    ("Stationary","Stationary"),
    ("Electronics","Electronics"),
    ("Food","Food"),
)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=cat_choices,null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Product'
        ordering = ['category']
```

and my forms.py has....

```
from django import forms
from .models import Product

class AddProduct(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name','category','quantity']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddProduct,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'text','id':'name','name':'name','class':'form-control','placeholder':'Product Name'})
        # self.fields['category'].widget = forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select'})
```

So I need a solution as to how I can style it or more appropriately which widget to use. I have already tried Select and it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `category` in your model to be an `IntegerField`:

```
cat_choices = (
    (0, "Stationary"),
    (1, "Electronics"),
    (2, "Food"),
)

class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=cat_choices, null=True)
    ...
```

then you can use `forms.select`